# ng-click window open has no response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<p ng-click='window.open("{{data.url}}","_self")'>{{data.name}}</p>
```

Anything wrong with this? I tried onclick too but I saw error in the console.

Comment: What did the error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ngClick != onClick

`ngClick` can only access items on the scope. To resolve this issue you can use the `$window` service inside of the controller action or add the $window onto the scope.

## Your expression is invalid

Your `ngClick` contains markup that needs to be interpolated. When inside of `ngClick` you do not need to use the `{{}}` syntax and can easily use the scope variable directly.

## Maybe use ngHref?

If all you are doing is opening up a window just use an anchor tag and [`ngHref`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

```
<a ng-href="{{data.url}}">{{data.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I must say you have to do it in controller with the help of $window service like this:-

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$window) {
 $scope.open=function(data){
    $window.open(data,"self")
  }
});
```

HTML:-

```
<p ng-click='open(data.url)'>{{data.name}}</p>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1mQzotVnyJWMff4TSey6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a directive:

```
<p window-open url="data.url">{{data.name}}</p>

app.directive('windowOpen', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      $window.open(attrs.url,"self");
    }
  };
});
```